# YouTube Feed has an object called @attributes how can I access it?

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

I am trying to get a YouTube RSS feed to work but I am struggling to get one of the attributes I need out of it.  I have never seen part of the array starting with an @ sign so I think it may be some sort of a special element but I'm not sure.  Code below and what I have already tried after.

**Feed:**

```
<?php
$xml->entry =
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
   'id' => 'yt:video:DjwM9SHJznM',
   'title' => 'JD19AT  - Joomla! in der Uni - Community-Arbeit als Lehrveranstaltung',
   'link' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     '@attributes' => 
    array (
      'rel' => 'alternate',
      'href' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjwM9SHJznM',
    ),
  )),
   'author' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     'name' => 'J and Beyond e.V.',
     'uri' => 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCy6ThiEDnalZOd_pgtpBk1Q',
  )),
   'published' => '2019-03-30T16:49:53+00:00',
   'updated' => '2019-05-09T16:56:18+00:00',
));
?>
```

**Code:**

```
$feed = $youtubeChannelFeed;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
$html = "";
```

This works `$xml->entry->title;`

but this doesn't `$xml->entry->link` it just says **"SimpleXML Object"**

As it says object I then tried using both `->` arrow and `['attribute']` notation.

I tried escaping the `@` with a `\@` but that just caused an error.

How can I traverse the tree and get the value of to `@attributes->href` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I always try to remember this is that you can use an arrow or brackets to access data in an array or object.

Array begins with A, but it chooses the one that's does not begin with A.  Object is the one left over.  That's how I remember it at least.

In this case, although it was calling it a `SimpleXMLObject` it was actually showing me that it's an `array` in the `print_r`.  So I had to use brackets to access like so:

`$xml->entry->link[0]['href']`

I couldn't work out how to access `@attributes` but I remember now that you don't need to know the name to access it, you can do it using number format too.

If I'm honest I don't really know how I could access the first part with arrows as that appears to be an array too.

Comment: Rather than using a debug output (which have to represent everything as arrays, because it's all they know about), it's best to work with SimpleXML objects by looking at the XML they actually represent. As [shown in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), the `->foo` notation is used for *elements* (also known as "tags"), and the `['foo']` notation for *attributes*. You only need the `[0]` if there's more than one element with the same name, and even then it will assume the first one if you leave it off.

Comment: Are you saying if I had written `$xml->entry->link['href']` it would have worked?  And to clarify the first point, you are saying I should look at the XML feed directly and not a `print_r`?

Comment: Yes, and yes. If the XML looks like `<document><entry><link href="blah" /></entry></document>`, then you have "entry element, link element, href attribute", so you know you need `$xml->entry->link['href']`, which can also be written `$xml->entry->link[0]['href']` or `$xml->entry[0]->link['href']` or `$xml->entry[0]->link[0]['href']`, if that makes sense for you in context.